# Java palindrome project: If/else

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java program for a project that finds whether or not a 3-digit number is a palindrome, and when I finished it I didn't realize that the instructions also said that it has to detect if it's a 3 digit number or not, and I can't figure out how to implement it into what I have.

I can't use Arrays or loops since we haven't gone over them in class and my professor doesn't want us to use anything we technically shouldn't know. It has to be all inputs and math to find the digits.

The code works but my issue is around the area where ints d1, d2 and d3 are initiated. I think I need to have the "`if (d1 == d3)`" nested inside another if statement that determines if the number is 3 digits or not. I've tried figuring it out myself over the last couple days but I'm stuck.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //user or computer generated number
        System.out.print("Enter 1 if you would like to enter a 3-digit number. Enter 2 if you would like to have the computer generate it. ");
        int firstChoice = input.nextInt();

        //user entered number
        if (firstChoice == 1) {

            //enter the 3 digit number
            System.out.print("Enter a 3-digit number: ");
            int userNumbers = input.nextInt();

            //3 user numbers
            int d1 = userNumbers / 100;
            int d2 = (userNumbers / 100) / 10;
            int d3 = userNumbers % 10;


            if (d1 == d3) {
                System.out.println(userNumbers + " is a palindrome");
            } else {
                System.out.print(userNumbers + " is not a palindrome");
            }

            //computer generated number
        } else if (firstChoice == 2) {

            int low = 0;
            int high = 10;

            //generate 3 random numbers
            int num1 = (int)(Math.random() * ((high - low) - 1) + low);
            int num2 = (int)(Math.random() * ((high - low) - 1) + low);
            int num3 = (int)(Math.random() * ((high - low) - 1) + low);

            //computer number is or isn't a palindrome
            if (num1 == num3) {
                System.out.println(num1 + "" + num2 + "" + num3 + "");
                System.out.print(num1 + "" + num2 + "" + num3 + " is a palindrome");
            } else {
                System.out.println(num1 + "" + num2 + "" + num3 + "");
                System.out.print(num1 + "" + num2 + "" + num3 + " is not a palindrome");
            }
            //incorrect input
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect input");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To check if it is a 3 digit number you can check if it is between 100 and 999. Is that what you want ?

Comment: Yes, essentially but the 3 numbers (d1, d2 and d3) also have to have their own values using the Scanner util, if that makes sense. They're 3 separate numbers and the output for d1, d2 and d3 are all numbers less than 10, and then just joined together in a print statement to look like one number.

Comment: So the statement to check if it is a 3 digit number is if(userNumbers <= 999 && userNumbers >=100)

Comment: By the way (x/100)/10 =  x / 1000 so thats not what you want you want x/10

Comment: I've tried that and variations of that but it still gives me the output that it isn't a palindrome and not the "incorrect input" like I have the statement setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
// user entered number  
if (firstChoice == 1) {
    int userNumbers;
    // enter the 3 digit number
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a 3-digit number: ");
        userNumbers = input.nextInt();
        if (userNumbers >= 100 && userNumbers <= 999) {
            // 3 user numbers
            int d1 = userNumbers / 100;
            int d3 = userNumbers % 10;

            if (d1 == d3) {
                System.out.println(userNumbers + " is a palindrome");
            } else {
                System.out.print(userNumbers + " is not a palindrome");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("The number has to be of 3 digits");
        }
    } while (!(userNumbers >= 100 && userNumbers <= 999));

    // computer generated number
} else if (firstChoice == 2) {
    // ...
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter 1 if you would like to enter a 3-digit number. Enter 2 if you would like to have the computer generate it. 1
Enter a 3-digit number: 12
The number has to be of 3 digits
Enter a 3-digit number: 2000
The number has to be of 3 digits
Enter a 3-digit number: 121
121 is a palindrome
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter 1 if you would like to enter a 3-digit number. Enter 2 if you would like to have the computer generate it. 1
Enter a 3-digit number: 123
123 is not a palindrome
```

You can also re-write the logic to check the computer-generated 3-digit random number as given below:

```
if (firstChoice == 1) {// user entered number
    int userNumbers;
    // enter the 3 digit number
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a 3-digit number: ");
        userNumbers = input.nextInt();
        if (userNumbers >= 100 && userNumbers <= 999) {
            // 3 user numbers
            int d1 = userNumbers / 100;
            int d3 = userNumbers % 10;

            if (d1 == d3) {
                System.out.println(userNumbers + " is a palindrome");
            } else {
                System.out.print(userNumbers + " is not a palindrome");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("The number has to be of 3 digits");
        }
    } while (!(userNumbers >= 100 && userNumbers <= 999));  
} else if (firstChoice == 2) {// computer generated number    
    int low = 0;
    int high = 1000;    
    // generate a 3-digit random number
    int num = (int) (Math.random() * ((high - low) - 1) + low);    
    int d1 = num / 100;
    int d3 = num % 10;    

    if (d1 == d3) {
        System.out.println(num + " is a palindrome");
    } else {
        System.out.print(num + " is not a palindrome");
    }
}
```

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt.

Comment: That still gives me an output that says the number isn't a palindrome.

Comment: @efan - I just checked it and it's giving the correct answer. Anyway, I've further updated it so that it keeps asking until the user enters a 3-digit number. Check again and let me know if you still have any issue with it.

Comment: Omg I just realized I was running the main program when I thought it was my scratch file being run ‍♂️. This worked, though! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To check if it is a 3-digit number, do something like this:

```
if(userNumbers>99 && userNumbers<1000){ 
    //has 3 digits
} else { 
    //doesnt have 3 digits, return
}
```

Comment: This is what I thought to do but when I enter a 4 or 2 digit number it still gives me the "not a palindrome" output and not the "incorrect input" one like I have setup. The userNumbers are basically just 3 separate numbers that are all less than 10 so it's not all one number.

Comment: In your code the variable userNumbers has a single value, which is divided into 3 numbers afterwards

Comment: @efan can you also please update your code with the new lines?

Comment: I just realized I was running the code from my main and not the scratch file that I had open ‍♂️. I'll test this answer in my main and I'm sure it'll work. Thank you so much.

Comment: @efan took me hours one time finding out that my declared variable was in main and not in class

Comment: LOL it really do be like that sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You also could convert it to string, so check if the length is not 3, if is 3 then compare characters at 0 and 2.
Also you should close Scanner at end.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //user or computer generated number
    System.out.print("Enter 1 if you would like to enter a 3-digit number. Enter 2 if you would like to have the computer generate it. ");
    Integer firstChoice = input.nextInt();

    //user entered number
    if (firstChoice == 1) {

        //enter the 3 digit number
        System.out.print("Enter a 3-digit number: ");
        Integer userNumbers = input.nextInt();

        String strNumber = userNumbers.toString(); 

        if (strNumber.length() != 3) {
            System.out.println("Number lenght should be 3");
        } else if (strNumber.charAt(0) == strNumber.charAt(2)) {
            System.out.println(userNumbers + " is a palindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.print(userNumbers + " is not a palindrome");
        }

        //computer generated number
    } else if (firstChoice == 2) {

        int low = 0;
        int high = 10;

        //generate 3 random numbers
        int num1 = (int)(Math.random() * ((high - low) - 1) + low);
        int num2 = (int)(Math.random() * ((high - low) - 1) + low);
        int num3 = (int)(Math.random() * ((high - low) - 1) + low);

        //computer number is or isn't a palindrome
        if (num1 == num3) {
            System.out.println(num1 + "" + num2 + "" + num3 + "");
            System.out.print(num1 + "" + num2 + "" + num3 + " is a palindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.println(num1 + "" + num2 + "" + num3 + "");
            System.out.print(num1 + "" + num2 + "" + num3 + " is not a palindrome");
        }
        //incorrect input
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect input");
    }

    input.close();
}
```